# Aggregating Nested Fields in Kibana /Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, kibana-6

I have defined an Index in elastic cache 6

```
PUT my_index
{
 "mappings": {
  "_doc": {
  "properties": {
    "user": {
      "type": "nested" 
       }
      }
     }
  }
 }
```

and loaded some same data as follows

```
 PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
 "group" : "coach",
"user" : [
    {
    "first" : "John",
    "last" :  "Frank"
   },
   {
    "first" : "Hero",
    "last" :  "tim"
   }
  ]
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
 "group" : "team",
"user" : [
    {
    "first" : "John",
    "last" :  "term"
   },
   {
    "first" : "david",
    "last" :  "gayle"
   }
  ]
}
```

Now I am trying to search in the discover page or the visualization page, but I receive a blank

[image: Loaded Data]

[image: Discover Search Results]

[image: Visualization]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a bit of trial and error and googling around i found that does not support nested type for aggregation and search out of the box. To enable this you must install a plugin and the best plugin i found is listed below.

https://ppadovani.github.io/knql_plugin/overview/

The plugin provides all the features from the discover tab to the visualization tab.

Comment: If you are using latest you can also use Vega visualization